# Android full screen without three dots

Tags: android, statusbar, navigationbar

I create empty app. I want set full screen without three dots(menu/search/back).
[image]

Please help!

Comment: you got some advance? Don't forget check one answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set in the manifest

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" .... >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tablet you cannot get rid of the system bar. You may be able to get rid of the navigation bar and status bar on phones. Please read the "Controls for system UI visibility" section of the Android 4.0 SDK release notes. http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.html